# Can't get jmeter-server to work correctly with jdbc:mysql driver

Tags: mysql, java, jdbc, jmeter

I am running jmeter-server on a remote database host (Centos, sun-java 1.6). I dropped the MySQL java jar in $JMETER_HOME/lib per the install instructions. When I try to run a job on my local system (OS X Lion), I get the following error on the server:

> 2013/04/10 12:44:43 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement: Could not return Connection java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://1.2.3.4/dbname 
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
>       at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.JdbcConnectionFactory.newInstance(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:185)
>       at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.ResourceLimitingPool.newPoolable(ResourceLimitingPool.java:672)
>       at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.newPoolable(ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.java:178)
>       at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.ResourceLimitingJdbcConnectionPool.newPoolable(ResourceLimitingJdbcConnectionPool.java:123)
>       at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.ResourceLimitingPool.get(ResourceLimitingPool.java:402)
>       at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.get(ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.java:130)
>       at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.ResourceLimitingJdbcDataSource.getConnection(ResourceLimitingJdbcDataSource.java:222)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement$DataSourceComponentImpl.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:286)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:146)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler.sample(JDBCSampler.java:85)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Anybody have any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the Percona MySQL version that we are running required a specific version of the connector.  Dropped that in and it all worked out.